# Best way to improve js scoping

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Hello everyone I'm trying to display some data when I make an HTTPRequest but when I call the function that retrieves a callback from the httprequets the scope of the function wont let me get to the data I want to display so I have to repeate code Im trying to find the best solution to not have to repeate same code sentences. TY in advance.

```
function loadJSON(callback) {
    var stringQuery = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.replace(/^.*?\=/, ''));   
    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xobj.open('GET', 'http://localhost:3000/data/?email='+stringQuery, true);
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
      callback(JSON.parse(xobj.responseText));
      }
    };
    xobj.send(null);  
  };
```

```
function gettingReportbyEmail(){
    var stringQuery = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.replace(/^.*?\=/, ''));
    var datos = {};
    var datos =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(stringQuery));
    if (datos == null) {
      loadJSON(function(response){
      localStorage.setItem(stringQuery, JSON.stringify(response[0]));
      var datos = {};   //This is where I have to repeate same code as above
      var datos =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(stringQuery));
      displayEmailandRelatives(datos);
      });  
    }else{
      datos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(stringQuery)); 
    }
  };
```

no errors just trying to find a better solution.

Comment: Don't use `var`. Use `const` or `let`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (datos == null) {
      loadJSON(function(response){
      localStorage.setItem(stringQuery, JSON.stringify(response[0]));
      datos = response[0];
      displayEmailandRelatives(datos);
      });  
    }
```

I don't see any purpose of setting the value to localStorage and reading the same value just to call a function.

Comment: I mean if there's no record on the local storage of the value searched then I have to go and make an httprequest and search it on my server if theres any record on there, thats the point if there's no data on the local storage than I call on the loadJson function to get the info from the server

Comment: I meant to say that there is no point of setting and getting the same value inside` `datos == null` if block. By calling loadJSON you made an HTTP call, in the response of this call, you are just setting the response[0] into the local storage and reading the same value. Why read from local storage if you already have the original variable in the same scope?

Answer (score 0):

simply remove the duplicated code and it should work

```
function gettingReportbyEmail(){
    var stringQuery = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.replace(/^.*?\=/, ''));
    // remove the code 
    if (datos == null) {
      loadJSON(function(response){
      localStorage.setItem(stringQuery, JSON.stringify(response[0]));
      displayEmailandRelatives(datos);
      });  
    }else{
      datos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(stringQuery)); 
    }
  };
```

it should work because of JavaScript Closures
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures